# Using c# matlab reference, diary not working

Tags: c#, matlab

So Im using matlab in my c# code, but when I use the diary it will create a file but it will be emtpy. I found a simlar question [here](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285043) but I have not seen a solution.

My code

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

matlab.Execute("diary");
matlab.Execute("disp('heej')");
...
...
matlab.Execute("disp('heej')");
matlab.Execute("disp('heej')");
matlab.Execute("disp('heej')");
matlab.Execute("diary off");
```

Any Ideas of how to use diary from a c# application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it does not seem like diary works when running it from a C# application, however you can use C# itself to save the output that Matlab gives you. I have made it so the output is sent to a terminal as well as a text file using **Trace**.

```
        Trace.Listeners.Clear();

        TextWriterTraceListener twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener(pathBuildDir + @"\log.txt");
        twtl.Name = "TextLogger";
        twtl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.ThreadId | TraceOptions.DateTime;

        ConsoleTraceListener ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false);
        ctl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime;

        Trace.Listeners.Add(twtl);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);
        Trace.AutoFlush = true;

        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

        Trace.WriteLine(matlab.Execute("pwd"));
        Trace.WriteLine(matlab.Execute(@"run('foobar.m')"));
        ...
        ...
```